# Is it possible to put a Refresh Controller in the Header of CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView` with a `Header` and I want to add a `RefreshController` to the `CollectionView` which I already did. It is showing **above** the `Header` as I would expect it to be. However I want the `RefreshController` to show **in** the `Header`.

The reason for this is, that a `Toolbar` is covering the `Header`. When I pull down to refresh, the `Header` gets visible in the way I want the `RefreshController` to get visible. But I would have to pull down for the height of the `Header` to make the `RefreshController` visible, which is
a) too large of a distance to scroll and
b) too much space between the `RefreshController` and the `CollectionView`

Here is some Code:

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    [...]
    
    refreshControl.tintColor = .gray
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = .white
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshContents), for: .valueChanged)
    eventCollectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    eventCollectionView.register(EventHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: toolbarId)
}

@objc func refreshContents() {
    self.perform(#selector(finishedRefreshing), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.5)
}
    
@objc func finishedRefreshing() {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return .init(width: screenWidth, height: 50)
}
```

EDIT: I didn't know about `contentInset` at the time of asking this question. By using `contentInset` as suggested by Larry Pickles I was able to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Can you share your code or screenshots?

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem added code to the question

Comment: sounds like you don't want this in the header and you dont want a header at all, but instead you want a custom refreshcontro. that has the refresh contrll and the stuff you would have included in the header. otherwise why cover the header with a toolbad? this seems like a wacky design.

Comment: @Loxx Yes you are right in some way. I just use the Header because I need some space for the toolbar between the CollectionView and the NavigationBar, so the CollectionView won't get covered by the toolbar. The toolbar is disappearing when scrolling down. I will add a gif, so you can maybe get what I try to say.

Comment: then just set the content inset of the collectionView, set the top to 50 points, this will solve it, no need for the header

Comment: also, if a tool bar is covering the collection view, you're setting your constraints incorrectly, you should set the top constraint of the collection to the bottom anchor of the toolbar, then you don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: @Loxx I think the content inset is what I was missing, didn't know about that. Should be way easier now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested my Larry Pickles in the comments, what I was looking for can be done by setting the top of the `contentInset` of the `collectionView` to 50. This way I don't even have to put the `RefreshController` into the `Header`.